# Different version information of c# (.net7) / powershell / explorer

Tags: c#, .net, powershell, explorer

currently i am a little bit confused about the versions i am able to get via native .net (C#), powershell and the windows explorer.

As you can see in the screenshot the C#-Code determines FileMajorPart=6 and FileMinorPart=2. I espected at least Major Version 10. Why is powershell displaying the correct versions even when using the same functions?

[image: IDE screenshot]

Also... It seems, that this only happens for some special files. Also calc.exe displays a wrong version. Other .exe-Files are displayed correctly.

C#:

```
using System.Diagnostics;

FileVersionInfo test = FileVersionInfo.GetVersionInfo(@"c:\windows\system32\notepad.exe");
```

Result:

```
-       test    {File:             c:\windows\system32\notepad.exe
InternalName:     Notepad
OriginalFilename: NOTEPAD.EXE.MUI
FileVersion:      10.0.19041.1 (WinBuild.160101.0800)
FileDescription:  Editor
Product:          Betriebssystem Microsoft® Windows®
ProductVersion:   10.0.19041.1
Debug:            False
Patched:          False
PreRelease:       False
PrivateBuild:     False
SpecialBuild:     False
Language:         Deutsch (Deutschland)
}   System.Diagnostics.FileVersionInfo
       ...
        FileMajorPart   6   int
        FileMinorPart   2   int
        FileName    "c:\\windows\\system32\\notepad.exe"    string
        FilePrivatePart 3636    int
        FileVersion "10.0.19041.1 (WinBuild.160101.0800)"   string
        ...
        ProductBuildPart    19041   int
        ProductMajorPart    10  int
        ProductMinorPart    0   int
        ProductName "Betriebssystem Microsoft® Windows®"    string
        ProductPrivatePart  3636    int
        ProductVersion  "10.0.19041.1"  string
        SpecialBuild    ""  string
```

Powershell:

```
PS C:\> [System.Diagnostics.FileVersionInfo]::GetVersionInfo("c:\windows\system32\notepad.exe") | fl *


FileVersionRaw     : 10.0.19041.3636
ProductVersionRaw  : 10.0.19041.3636
Comments           :
CompanyName        : Microsoft Corporation
FileBuildPart      : 19041
FileDescription    : Editor
FileMajorPart      : 10
FileMinorPart      : 0
FileName           : c:\windows\system32\notepad.exe
FilePrivatePart    : 3636
FileVersion        : 10.0.19041.1 (WinBuild.160101.0800)
InternalName       : Notepad
IsDebug            : False
IsPatched          : False
IsPrivateBuild     : False
IsPreRelease       : False
IsSpecialBuild     : False
Language           : Deutsch (Deutschland)
LegalCopyright     : © Microsoft Corporation. Alle Rechte
                     vorbehalten.
LegalTrademarks    :
OriginalFilename   : NOTEPAD.EXE.MUI
PrivateBuild       :
ProductBuildPart   : 19041
ProductMajorPart   : 10
ProductMinorPart   : 0
ProductName        : Betriebssystem Microsoft® Windows®
ProductPrivatePart : 3636
ProductVersion     : 10.0.19041.1
SpecialBuild       :
```

Do you have any idea, why this could happen?

I am using .net 7.0 for c#.

Thank you in advance and regards,
Wolfgang

I tried using different tools like powershell / windows explorer.

Comment: you aren't allowed to post images of code

Comment: just added an imgur-link. hope this helps :)

Comment: I have no clue why this is happening, but the Product Version seems to be correct. Could you use that instead?

Comment: Also, as @nbk said, posting images of code is generally frowned upon. In your case showing an image of the File Explorer properties window seems fine, but try to show the c# and powershell code (and output) as text.

Comment: thank you - i will add the code as text later - very new to this community but willing to learn :-)

Comment: Regarding screenshots, to elaborate on JeanotZubler's comment:  They're fine if used to _complement_ the relevant information provided _as text_. Here's a link to the standard advice: Please (also) post your code, data, error messages as ([properly formatted](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting)) _text_, [not (just) as _images_](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/45375).

Comment: Smells like 32-bit vs 64-bit. Compare C:\Windows\System32\notepad.exe to C:\Windows\SysWOW64\notepad.exe.

Answer (score 0):

- There are **Windows system APIs that *situationally* report *legacy* information for the sake of backward compatibility**, notably with respect to the ***OS version***.

  - This seemingly also **applies to the *file-version information* of executables and libraries that *ship with Windows***, such as Notepad.
  - A caveat is that the `.FileVersion` and `.ProductVersion` properties of the .NET [`System.Diagnostics.FileVersionInfo`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Diagnostics.FileVersionInfo) type are "cooked" values that *mask* the legacy behavior, but the underlying version number component-individual properties (`.FileMajorPar`, `.FileMinorPart`, ...) do report the legacy values, if applicable.
- The **behavior** of these APIs **depends on whether the querying application has an [application manifest](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/sbscs/application-manifests)**, and, if so, what version of Windows that manifest specifies.

  - Specifically, it is the `ID` attribute of the [`supportedOS`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/sbscs/application-manifests#supportedOS) element that declares the compatible Windows version.
  - In the **absence of a manifest**, applications see legacy values that applied to Windows *Vista*, namely **`6.2` as the OS version**.
  - [Operating System Version](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/sysinfo/operating-system-version) shows the detailed mapping. Notably, **on Windows *11* it is still `10.0` that is reported.**
- To **discover the manifested behavior of a given application**:

  - Launch the application and keep it open.
  - Start Task Manager (`taskmgr.exe`) and switch to its `Details` view ([image: Details view icon] in the left sidebar)
  - Right-click on the column headers, click on 'Select columns`and add the`Operating system context` column to the view (scroll down until you see it - the list is *not* sorted by name).
  - You'll see the following:

    - (no value) ... the application is manifested for Windows 10, Windows 11, Windows Server 2016, Windows Server 2019 and Windows Server 2022 (the *same* GUID is used for all of them).
    - `Windows Vista` ... the application has either *no* manifest or was manifested for Vista explicitly.
    - `Windows 8`, `Windows 8.1` ... the application was explicitly manifested for these versions.

---

Your screenshot implies that the IDE you're using has NO application manifest, which explains the values you're seeing.

Note that both Windows PowerShell (`powershell.exe`) and [*PowerShell (Core) 7+*](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/blob/master/README.md) (`pwsh.exe`) *are* manifested for Windows 10+, which is why you saw `10.0` values in the output from the command you ran (in-process) in a PowerShell session.

The same applies analogous to using the File Explorer GUI for inspecting file properties.